# DIVIDIR valores totales de 2 tablas en MySql

Tags: mysql

En un post anterior y con la idea de este foro, pude lograr sumar los valores de 2 tablas que en la estructura son identicas.

> select sum(AP) AP, sum(T) T, sum(CA) CA, sum(H) H, sum(2H) 2H, sum(3H)
>   3H, sum(HR) HR, sum(CE) CE, sum(BB) BB, sum(P) P, sum(BR) BR, sum(SF)
>   SF, sum(TB) TB from (
>       select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from stats where id=10 union all
>       select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from  stats2017 where id=6 ) x

y correctamente me monstró la suma de las 2 tablas.

Ahora en lo que estoy perdido es en calcular el promedio es diviendiendo el valor total entre ***H/T***, pero debe ser de la sumatoria de los 2 tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEMA RESUELTO

Tenia este query que solo me sumaba los datos de mis 2 tablas `select sum(AP) AP, sum(T) T, sum(CA) CA, sum(H) H, sum(2H) 2H, sum(3H) 3H, sum(HR) HR, sum(CE) CE, sum(BB) BB, sum(P) P, sum(BR) BR, sum(SF) SF, sum(TB) TB from ( select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from stats where id=10 union all select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from stats2017 where id=6 ) x` **Lo que hice fue entonces agregar** `FORMAT(sum(H)/sum(T),3) Promedio` **justamente antes del from**

Comment: Aunque esto puede que resuelva el problema, deberias explicar un poco mas la solucion. Mira [answer]

Comment: Aunque esto puede que resuelva el problema, deberias explicar un poco mas la solucion. Mira [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: Tenia este query que solo me sumaba los datos de mis 2 tablas `select sum(AP) AP, sum(T) T, sum(CA) CA, sum(H) H, sum(2H) 2H, sum(3H) 3H, sum(HR) HR, sum(CE) CE, sum(BB) BB, sum(P) P, sum(BR) BR, sum(SF) SF, sum(TB) TB from ( select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from stats where id=10 union all select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from stats2017 where id=6 ) x` **Lo que hice fue entonces agregar** `FORMAT(sum(H)/sum(T),3) Promedio` **justamente antes del from**

Answer (score 0):

select sum(AP) AP, sum(T) T, sum(CA) CA, sum(H) H, sum(2H) 2H, sum(3H) 3H, sum(HR) HR, sum(CE) CE, sum(BB) BB, sum(P) P, sum(BR) BR, sum(SF) SF, sum(TB) TB from ( select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from stats where id=10 union all select AP, T, CA, H, 2H, 3H, HR, CE, BB, P, BR, SF, TB from stats2017 where id=6 ) x
agregar FORMAT(sum(H)/sum(T),3) Promedio